# binding dropdownlist values to textbox

Tags: asp.net

When the user selects an order ID, the rest of the order information is displayed in label(s). Display the following: employee ID, order date, freight, shipped name, and country. This functionality should be implemented using direct data access programmatically.

Edit: code example and additional explanation.

```
String CS = onfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NORTHWNDConnectionString"].ConnectionStr‌​ing; 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) 
{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderID FROM Orders", con);
    con.Open();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "OrderID";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "OrderID";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text); 
}
```

What I want is the other fields which are there in orders table to be displayed when a value is selected in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This reads like a copied and pasted question from an assignment?

Comment: this sounds like a requirement rather than a question :)

Comment: using the database i have populated the values from the database to the dropdownlist..what i want to do know is to display the fields of that selected value in the label

Comment: what i want is i want the other fields which are there in orders table to be displayed when a value is selected in dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Can you make datatable from the SQL Query result, and then add items to dropdownlist from ID column. When you then select an item from DDL, you show the info where the row from datatable match the selected orderID.

I can write code if you want it isn't cleared what I'm meaning.

UPDATE: with code

```
var ds = new DataSet();

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    conn.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("Your SQL Query", conn);
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
 } //Now you have a dataset, with one table that matches your query result.

//And now we can use a foreach loop to add every OrderID to dropdownlis

 foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
 {
     foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
     {
         DDLname.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
     }
 }

//onSelectedValue event
string orderID = DDLname.Text.toString();
Label1.Text = orderID;
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        if(dr[0].toString().equals(orderID))
        {
            Label2.text = dr[1].toString();
            Label3.text = dr[2].toString();
            etc....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ...how to remove this error

Comment: Almost every thing can use the toString()  method. Can you see what object that is getting the message? I think visual studio gives you a codeline refrence.

Answer (score 0):

As you labelled your question with ASP.Net, I assume that this is part of an ASP.Net Webforms application. This means that the drop down list will be inside a web page in a browser. Not clear to me is whether you want the label to be displayed immediately when the user select the item, or only after a post to the server. 
In the first case, you'll need javascript and probably something like Ajax or JSON to get the data you want to display for the selected item. In the second case, you could add an event handler for the SelectedIndex_Changed Event of your drop down list. This handler should do something like this:

```
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NORTHWNDConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderID FROM Orders WHERE OrderId = @OrderId", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
        con.Open();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Label1.Text = String.Format("Employee ID: {0}, order date: {1}, freight: {2}, shipped name: {3}, and country {4}."
                , reader["employeeid"].ToString()
                , reader["orderdate"].ToString()
                , reader["freight"].ToString()
                , reader["shipname"].ToString()
                , reader["shipcountry"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Label1.Text = String.Format("Employee ID: {0}, order date: {1}, freight: {2}, shipped name: {3}, and country {4}."), reader["employeeId"].ToString(), reader["orderDate"].ToString(), reader["freight"].ToString(), reader["shippedName"].ToString(), reader["country"].ToString());

Comment: I have pasted this code in my SelectedIndex_Changed Event  but i am facing some kind of error in this line..like before the reader starts ; is expected

Comment: @user2540165 there were some typo's in the code. I pasted it in VS.Net and now it should compile fine.

Comment: Hello i am getting an index out of range exception for this code

Comment: In order to get it correct, I downloaded and installed [Northwind and pubs Sample Databases for SQL Server 2000](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23654), didn't have them, but can come in handy anyway. It appeared that the field names for shipping fields were no correct. Also, I added a reader.Read() to populate the first record. I hope it works correctly now.

Comment: thank you i figured out my mistake..but i am not getting the correct result

Comment: @user2540165, I can only help you further of you make clear what's going wrong now. In your question you mentioned "onSelectedValue event". Could you explain which control generates this event? Is this JavaScript? Could you post more code?